# GAE @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE) not generating sequential numbers

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I've a field:

[image]

When I put it in :
[image]

It does not get generated sequentially
[image]

Any reason why the sequence numbers are not in order? I'll add the logs in 2 seperate posts because they are too big for this post.

```
1:1422624487.413000 [s~server-test-killesk/12.381882801386260762].<stdout>: 13:28:07,413 DEBUG Request FC14E205 ValueGeneration:debug:58 - Creating ValueGenerator instance of "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.valuegenerator.SequenceGenerator" for "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJobEvent.sequence"
1:1422624487.424000 [s~server-test-killesk/12.381882801386260762].<stdout>: 13:28:07,423 DEBUG Request FC14E205 ValueGeneration:debug:58 - Generated value for field "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJobEvent.sequence" using strategy="sequence" (Generator="com.google.appengine.datanucleus.valuegenerator.SequenceGenerator") : value=1,050,002
1:1422624487.624000 [s~server-test-killesk/12.381882801386260762].<stdout>: 13:28:07,624 DEBUG Request FC14E205 ValueGeneration:debug:58 - Generated value for field "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJobEvent.sequence" using strategy="sequence" (Generator="com.google.appengine.datanucleus.valuegenerator.SequenceGenerator") : value=1,040,003
1:1422624487.908000 [s~server-test-killesk/12.381882801386260762].<stdout>: 13:28:07,907 DEBUG Request FC14E205 ValueGeneration:debug:58 - Generated value for field "com.eurekaapp.server.dao.mappedobjects.DAOJobEvent.sequence" using strategy="sequence" (Generator="com.google.appengine.datanucleus.valuegenerator.SequenceGenerator") : value=3,010,003
```

Comment: It might not be possible. Please see this link:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/Zl5v7QnuFJ4

Comment: Thanks for the comment Neil. I'll take away all the @Default annotations. I need to read up more about JDO technology. Thanks for your comment though, it really helped answer my question.

Comment: Killesk ..were you able to achieve sequential number by (valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE) ? In above comment, You said removing @persistent for every field really helped answer your question? So just want to confirm did that helped?

Comment: @Vivek Nope, I could get it working locally but once I pushed to the live system, it would give me random values. I think I read that because it's a cloud based system, it's using many different databases and so every time you create a new row on a different database, you'll get a different value.

Comment: Also, sorry, I was being very sarcastic with my first comment. That Neil guy didn't help me at all. He just commented on how I was using @Persistent incorrectly.

Comment: yeah :)...same happened to me gave a very different value for each entry. Anyways thanks for confirming !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE` is implemented on top of [`DatastoreService.allocateIds()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.html#allocateIds-com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key-java.lang.String-long-) which is how Cloud Datastore internally assigns Ids. Everything that applies to Cloud Datastore auto-Id allocation applies to SEQUENCE.

Sequences are only guaranteed to be unique, not monotonically increasing.